# Listing function parameters at top of file

Tags: c#, doxygen

I am trying to write a class where the functions, in general, all take the same or similar input arguments. What I would like to do is provide a list of the parameters at the top of the class and reference those parameters at the function class (in order to save a few key strokes.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

I was trying to do something like the following.

```
public static class TestClass
{   
    /// <param name="p1">A test parameter</param>
    /// <param name="p2">Another test parameter</param>

    /// <summary>
    /// Does something
    /// </summary>
    /// A more detailed something
    /// <paramref name="p1"/>
    /// <paramref name="p2"/>
    public static void TestFunction(double p1, double p2)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

edit:
This is really just a static class of standalone functions. Thus it has no internal parameters. The code was updated.

Comment: If I understood your question, will a constructor serve your need? where you will send your parameters to it at the creation of the class, save them into private member fields then use these fields within your functions in the class.

Comment: sounds like class level vars; just because they are at the top means nothing, but settings them in the ctor makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i've refactored your parameters to class fields:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        private readonly double _p1;
        private readonly double _p2;

        public TestClass( double p1 , double p2 )
        {
            _p1 = p1;
            _p2 = p2;
        }
        public void TestFunction( /* use other parameters specifc for this method*/ )
        {
            // use  your fields here
            var p1 = _p1;
            var p2 = _p2;
        }
    }
```